# Inserting Nodes of HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't exactly specialize in javascript so I need a tad of a help in an implementation of a script. Excuse the noob level of such a question.
I'll show you this image to give you a general idea of what I want:

[image]

So in short terms, the '+' sign would add another ingredient div and the minus would remove one. I tried DOM Nodes except there's a tiny part I got stuck at. Right now this is with jquery so;

```
$('#add-ingredient').on('click', function() {
    ingredient_count += 1
    var para = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createTextNode('<div class="col col-3-12 left"></div><div id="ingredient-'+i+'" class="col col-9-12 right"><div class="col col-2-12 input"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-qty" placeholder="quantity" /> </div> <div class="col col-3-12 input"> <select class="r-title"> <option value="empty"></option> <?php for($in=0;$in<=$ing_count;$in++){echo "<option value=".$ing[$in]['ing_id'].">".$ing[$in]['ing_name']."</option>"; } ?> <option value="other">other</option> </select> </div> <div class="col col-4-12"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-name" placeholder="ingredient" /> </div> <div id="add-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div> <div id="remove-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div></div>');
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("row-2");
    element.appendChild(para);
});
```

I want to append that HTML script however not in a text form, rather in the HTML form. I've tried `document.write()` but that re-write the whole page.

So how can I make it insert the HTML rather then just the text?

Comment: Don't put `[solved]` in the title. Accepting an answer is how you indicate that it was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating a things simply use this script

```
$('#add-ingredient').on('click', function() {
ingredient_count += 1
$('#row-2').append('<div><div class="col col-3-12 left"></div><div id="ingredient-'+i+'" class="col col-9-12 right"><div class="col col-2-12 input"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-qty" placeholder="quantity" /> </div> <div class="col col-3-12 input"> <select class="r-title"> <option value="empty"></option> <?php for($in=0;$in<=$ing_count;$in++){echo "<option value=".$ing[$in]['ing_id'].">".$ing[$in]['ing_name']."</option>"; } ?> <option value="other">other</option> </select> </div> <div class="col col-4-12"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-name" placeholder="ingredient" /> </div> <div id="add-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div> <div id="remove-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div></div></div>'); });
```

Comment: This one's efficient, I'll go with this. o.o

Answer (score 3):

If you want the HTML to be interpreted, assign it to `.innerHTML`, don't create a text node.

```
para.innerHTML = '<div class="col col-3-12 left"></div><div id="ingredient-'+i+'" class="col col-9-12 right"><div class="col col-2-12 input"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-qty" placeholder="quantity" /> </div> <div class="col col-3-12 input"> <select class="r-title"> <option value="empty"></option> <?php for($in=0;$in<=$ing_count;$in++){echo "<option value=".$ing[$in]['ing_id'].">".$ing[$in]['ing_name']."</option>"; } ?> <option value="other">other</option> </select> </div> <div class="col col-4-12"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-name" placeholder="ingredient" /> </div> <div id="add-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div> <div id="remove-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div></div>';
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought there was some other function for it which I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery , with this like code:

```
$('#add-ingredient').on('click', function() {
var clone=$(this).parent().clone();
$(this).parent().after(clone);
});
```

Comment: This works too except I don't need to clone it since they have different IDs. I've solved it tho, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can us do something like this:

```js
para.appendChild($.parseHTML('<div class="col col-3-12 left"></div><div id="ingredient-'+i+'" class="col col-9-12 right"><div class="col col-2-12 input"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-qty" placeholder="quantity" /> </div> <div class="col col-3-12 input"> <select class="r-title"> <option value="empty"></option> <?php for($in=0;$in<=$ing_count;$in++){echo "<option value=".$ing[$in]['ing_id'].">".$ing[$in]['ing_name']."</option>"; } ?> <option value="other">other</option> </select> </div> <div class="col col-4-12"> <input type="text" class="r-title" name="recipe-ing-name" placeholder="ingredient" /> </div> <div id="add-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div> <div id="remove-ingredient" class="col col-1-12 btn btn-add"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div></div>'));
var element = document.getElementById("row-2");
element.appendChild(para);
```